# Sample correlation coefficient transformed

Tags: distributions, correlation, data-transformation

If the sample correlation coefficient for the set of data consisting of the three pairs of values $(-1,-2),(0,0),(1,1)$ is 0.982.. After the $x$ and $y$ values have been transformed by particular linear functions, the data become $(2,2),(6,-4),(10,-7).$ What's the correlation coefficient for the transformed data?

My attempt, I guess the answer would be $-0.982$. But why would it be?

Comment: By definition, the correlation coefficient must not change under linear transformations.  For intuition, contemplate any formula you might know to compute the correlation coefficient and work out its units of measurement: it is *unitless,* demonstrating that changing the units in $x$ and $y$ will not alter it.  Your linear functions merely effect changes of units.

Answer (score 0):

Partially answered in comments:

By definition, the correlation coefficient must not change under linear transformations. For intuition, contemplate any formula you might know to compute the correlation coefficient and work out its units of measurement: it is unitless, demonstrating that changing the units in $x$ and $y$ will not alter it. Your linear functions merely effect changes of units. – whuber