# Correlation coefficient $(Y=aX+b)$

Tags: self-study, correlation, variance

Consider two random variables $X$ and $Y$.

Assume now that $Y=aX+b$ where $a<0$ and $-\infty<b<\infty$. Determine the value of the correlation coefficient $\rho(X,Y)$.

My attempt.

$$\rho(X,aX+b)=\frac{cov(X,aX+b)}{\sqrt{Var(X)Var(aX+b)}}$$

My question is how to compute $cov(X,aX+b)$? The given solution in the book $cov(X,aX+b)=aV(X)$. But I do not know how. Hope someone can explain it to me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to use the definition of the covariance with expected values: $\text{Cov}(X, Y) = E((X-E(X))(Y-E(Y))$?

Comment: ...and the [properties of expected value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Basic_properties)

Comment: This is really the same question you asked at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/360932/sample-correlation-coefficient-transformed, phrased in another way.